# Neo4j cypher - Compare two collections to get at least one same element

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher

I want to return all users that I follow who are not members of any groups that I am in. If a followed user is a member of *even one* group that I am in, it should not be returned.

However, I am getting an error:

```
None.get

Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure
```

when I try this query:

```
MATCH (g1:groups)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(u1:users{userid1:"56"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(u2:users)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g2:groups)
WITH collect(g1.groupid) AS my_groups,u2,collect(g2.groupid) AS foll_groups
WHERE NOT any(t in foll_groups WHERE t IN extract(x IN my_groups))
RETURN u2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
MATCH (g1:groups)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(u1:users { userid1:"56" })-[:FOLLOWS]->(u2:users)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g2:groups)
WITH u2, collect(g2) AS foll_groups, collect(g1) AS my_groups
WITH u2, reduce(dup = FALSE, g IN foll_groups | (dup OR g IN my_groups)) AS has_dup
WHERE NOT has_dup
RETURN u2;
```